# Why I get this broken Bootstrap carousel in the VStudio 2019 standard project template?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core

When I create a new Web MVC project in VisualStudio 2019 (v16.11) I get this strange effect on carousel buttons. In particular, they are shaded and bordered.

I've checked, Visual Studio is using Bootstrap v4.3.1 in this template.

Down below the code I copied & pasted from the standard [Bootstrap 4 carousel template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/carousel/).

Why carousel buttons are not rendering correctly?

Original `Home/Index.cshtml` page screenshot:

[image]

After copying & pasting the relevant Bootstrap 4 carousel code screenshot:

[image]

The final page source:

```
@{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
<div class="text-center">
<h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
<p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p></div>

@* Copied carousel code starts here *@

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="active"></li>
</ol>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label=" :  " preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title> </title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em"> </text></svg>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-left">
                <h1>Example headline.</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the first slide of the carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Sign up today</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label=" :  " preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title> </title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em"> </text></svg>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption">
                <h1>Another example headline.</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the second slide of the carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Learn more</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <svg class="bd-placeholder-img" width="100%" height="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" role="img" aria-label=" :  " preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" focusable="false"><title> </title><rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="#777"></rect><text x="50%" y="50%" fill="#777" dy=".3em"> </text></svg>

        <div class="container">
            <div class="carousel-caption text-right">
                <h1>One more for good measure.</h1>
                <p>Some representative placeholder content for the third slide of this carousel.</p>
                <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="#">Browse gallery</a></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</button>
<button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
</button>
```

**EDIT:** This is the header of the *wwwroot\lib\bootstrap\dist\css\boostrap.css* file

```
/*!
* Bootstrap v4.3.1 (https://getbootstrap.com/)
* Copyright 2011-2019 The Bootstrap Authors
* Copyright 2011-2019 Twitter, Inc.
* Licensed under MIT 
(https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/LICENSE)
*/
```

Comment: The templates actually use Bootstrap v5.1.0.

Comment: I've edited the question with the *boostrap.css* file header. Depending on the VStudio version the Bootstrap version changes. The VStudio version is included in the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap v4.3.1 is used in the template but you copied carousel from v4.6.x example:

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/**4.6**/examples/carousel/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/examples/carousel/)

Instead copy carousel from v4.3.x example:

[https://getbootstrap.com/docs/**4.3**/examples/carousel/](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/carousel/)

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce the issue on Visual Studio 2019. I created an Asp.Net Core MVC project that has 4.3.1 JQuery by default.

When I added the carousel code then it generates the result you shared in the question.

It looks like the issue is caused by some missing file references.

To fix the issue, I suggest you add the code below in the `Head` part of the `_Layout.cshtml` page.

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
```

After that try to run the project.

**Output:**

[image]

Later, you could save those files and add them to your project.

Comment: `bootstrap.bundle.js` already include `popper.js` so you don't need both. It's usually preferred to put any js scripts at the bottom of `<body>` element. Also you are adding bootstrap v4.6.1 while @abenci said bootstrap v4.3.1 is already included in the template.